# How to set conditional breakpoint while debugging F# in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, f#

Consider this:

```
let hank = "hank"
let bill = "bill"
printfn "%A" hank  // for breakpoint
```

Now if I set a conditional breakpoint in VS2015, condition being "hank = bill" (assuming F# expression) I get the following error:

*The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute. The condition was 
'hank = bill'. The error returned was 'The breakpoint condition must 
evaluate to a boolean operation'.*

When the condition is "hank == bill" (maybe try C# expression?) the error is:

*The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute. The condition was 
'hank == bill'. The error returned was 'The runtime has refused to 
evaluate the expression at this time.'.*

Comment: Haven't used VS2015, but in earlier versions you'd use C# syntax.

Comment: The same works in VS 2015. Watches and breakpoint conditions use C# syntax

Answer (score 4):

The debugger uses C# syntax for conditions in breakpoints (in all versions of F# in Visual Studio, as far as I know), so the expression to use is `hank == bill`. I certainly used conditional breakpoints in F# with VS 2015 - some assorted thoughts on what might help:

- I think the debugger sometimes starts behaving oddly when you do too many things. Did you try to set the breakpoint in the second way after restarting the debugger?
- Sometimes, setting breakpoints immediately on `let` is a bit odd (the compiled code first initializes the variable to `defaultof<'T>`). Can you try adding some no-op statement like `printfn "test"` and setting conditional breakpoint on that?

Comment: Nothing strange; using this as isolated example, is consistent, have restarted VS, etc.  Already setting the breakpoint on a printfn line folling the let statements (clarified my sample).